# How to convert a column of date string to dates in R

Tags: r, date, csv

I have a csv file that I use read.csv to read in as so

```
ff = read.csv('ff5.csv',  col.names = c('date','mkt', 'smb','hml','rmw','cma','rf'), colClasses = c('character',rep('numeric',6)))
```

The date column is in the form of '197007'. It only gives the year and month, so I resort to as.yearmon in zoo package to convert the date column as so

```
as.Date(as.yearmon(date,'%Y%m'))
```

Now for each entry in the date column, it works. But when I try to assign it back to the column entry like so, it gives me numbers in character!

```
library(zoo)

ff = read.csv('ff5.csv',  col.names = c('date','mkt', 'smb','hml','rmw','cma','rf'), colClasses = c('character',rep('numeric',6)))

for (i in 1:length(ff$date)){
  date = ff$date[i]
  d = as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(date),'%Y%m'))
  ff$date[i] = d
}
```

How should I solve this? Data can be downloaded here

http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_5_Factors_2x3_CSV.zip

Comment: you're reading in the date as a character vector. This means that, when you convert date[i] to a date and put it back into ff$date, it has to convert it to a character because the vector it is going into is a character (ff$date). Assign d to ff$date2 instead of ff$date and that should clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a loop.

```
txt <- "197007
198511
201512"

library(zoo)
ff <- read.table(text=txt, col.names = "date")
ff$date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(ff$date), "%Y%m"))

str(ff)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ date: Date, format: "1970-07-01" "1985-11-01" ...
```